# How to solve this closure completion handler issue?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, closures, completionhandler

I have been stuck for almost two days death staring into these functions and want to know why I can't get my desired result.

Here's the first function:

```
   func getTheSchoolID(completion: @escaping ((String?)-> ())) {
    db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user!.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")

        } else {
            self.skoolID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String))
            }
        }
    }

    let fixedID = "\(skoolID)"
    let substrings = fixedID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
    let realString = String(substrings)
    completion(realString)

}
```

This was the function in an answer given to my last StackOverflow question so I used it and sort of understand the closure completion handler concept.

This next block of code is what I want to happen but doesn't happen.

```
    getTheSchoolID { [weak self] (realString) in
        if let id = realString {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.schoolIDTextF.text = id

            }
        }
    }
```

Now when i check the textfield in the Viewcontroller it's still empty.
[image: The Viewcontroller with the School ID textfield on the bottom.]

The collection path is fine the field is correct I'll even add a screenshot of my firestore database for reference. [image: Firestore Database]

If anyone can help that would be great. I'll even send a $10 Paypal payment if you give me the answer and it works. That's how much it means to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getDocuments` works asynchronously, you have to call `completion` **inside** the closure

```
func getTheSchoolID(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user!.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            self.skoolID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return SchoolID(schoolID: document.get("school_id") as! String)
            }
            let fixedID = "\(self.skoolID)"
            let substrings = fixedID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
            let realString = String(substrings)
            completion(realString)
        }
    }
}
```

And you are using too many parentheses.

And the `map` expression looks pretty weird.

Comment: Awesome thanks it Works. Do you still want $10? @vadian

Answer (score 1):

You call the closure too early. You need to call it inside the `db...getDocuments` closure, like:

```
func getTheSchoolID(completion: @escaping ((String?)-> ())) {
    db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user!.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")

        } else {
            self.skoolID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String))
            }
            let fixedID = "\(skoolID)"
            let substrings = fixedID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
            let realString = String(substrings)
            completion(realString)
        }
    }
}
```

And keep your money to buy a good book :-)